# SSH login to server using Ruby on Rails web application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails

i am developing an application using Ruby On Rails where I am displaying a link button. On a click of this button i want to ssh login to another server say

```
 ssh root@abc.com
```

I want to open the terminal  on a click of button and user should already be logged in there(internally providing password for ssh login). Anybody tell me how to do it? should i do it using JAVA or J Ruby?

Comment: do you have a web application and want to open the terminal window on the client side? Should the login information come from the server or the client?

Comment: yes.. on client side i want to open it.. n clinent infrmation will come from server side

Comment: well, there can't be a way to open e native ssh on the client side.

First, the sandbox of the browser (should) prohibit any activity outside the browser.

Second, what terminal? PuTTY, xterm, Terminal.app? It depends on the client operating system.

You would need some Java terminal emulation and open a server shell in that emulation that executes the ssh to the other server.

Comment: ok.. can i provide a terminal on browser itself? something like virtual terminal?

Comment: how can i do it using gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Java Terminal emulation like [JCTerm](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/) or [dragonconsole](https://github.com/bbuck/dragonconsole) or google for `java browser terminal emulation`